# How do I slow down the creep wave in Dota 2?

Tags: dota-2

I watch higher level games, and I see heroes slow down the creep wave to place it more on their side of the map. When I try it, I can't get the creeps to get caught on my hero. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you stand in front of a creep he will try to pass on your left/right side,so you need to **adequately move slightly left/right** to block him from passing around you.As long as you keep blocking the first creep on the head of the wave,the creeps that follow will block each other.And avoid scattering the wave(with spells,other heroes,courier...) since creeps that are further away from group will have different pathfinding and could pass you from weird directions.

It is best to start blocking **near your Tier 2 tower**,since at that point your creeps will be nicely lined up.

If you have another **teammate** in the lane it is best that one blocks the creeps and other one stays  further in front of the group.So if a creep bypasses you,your teammate will be there ready to block him,while you go ahead in case creep passes him too.

Blocking gets easier with **larger heroes**(pudge,lucifer...) since you have to maneuver less,and if **hero is slower** you will less likely move too far on the sides which could make the creep pass by you and ruin the block.

**Pulling** you can attack the neutral creeps(side lanes) and lead them close to your creeps on lane making them fight behind your tower and delaying the creeps progress.

Since patch **6.79** creeps in the safe lane have a **bonus movement speed** for few seconds when they initially spawn,making them harder to block.[Watch for more details.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1zXgkSW-yM)

**Hero Skills** (this is prohibited by some tournament rules)

- **Earthshaker** can use "fissure" on certain places and completely block the creeps from progressing(for the
  duration).
- **Furion** can use "sprout" to trap the creeps(if you manage to group them enough).
- **Clockwerk**  can use "cogs" to trap the creeps(if you manage to group them enough).

**Videos**

- [Creep blocking](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsn0o-8jgII)
- [Pulling](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_cAwEealcyg)
- [Furion Sprout](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OEWWQxEaa9E)
- [Earthshaker fissure](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=orh3aZ60lfs)

Comment: tl;dr: zigzag in front of the lane. Just try it in a few practice games and you'll get the hang of it in 5 minutes.

Comment: Don't forget Clockwrek can trap creeps with Power Cogs too.

Comment: as Decency said, the trick is to zigzag, do not stop walking, just make waves ...

Comment: @Arremer you meant Tier 2 tower instead of Tire 2 i suppose? could not edit that because of character limit :P

Comment: yes,no tires here xD

Comment: By the way, since bounty runes have been introduced into the game, it's usually more beneficial to go and secure one or both of the runes at the start of the game than it is to block the creeps. However, if you're quick (and in mid), you can get one rune and then run to the wave and start blocking halfway between tier 1 and 2 towers.